# Logging of threads in different log file

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, log4j

I have java class which is using threading in java. Currently i am using two threads and i want that every thread will write it's logs in its own log file. I am using log4j for this. But my java program is showing me an abnormal behavior. I am able to create two different log file but i can see that , in my first log file , there are logging message from both thread one or two and in second log file only second thread messages are there, but i want separate logging for the both threads.

here is my thread file

```
public class MainController extends Thread{   
 public static synchronized void main(String args[])
 {  
  ServerAccess t1=new ServerAccess("IP","root","zoomcallrec","cat /var/log/callrec/core1.log","com.ef.ThreadOne","Thread One");  
  ServerAccess t2=new ServerAccess("IP","root","zoomcallrec","cat /var/log/callrec/core1.log","com.ef.ThreadTwo","Thread Two");  
  t1.start();  

  t2.start();  
 }  
}
```

Here is my log4j File

```
log4j.logger.com.ef.ThreadOne=DEBUG, ThreadFirst

log4j.appender.ThreadFirst=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ThreadFirst.File=C:/AnalyzerLog/ThreadOne/Analyzer.log
log4j.appender.ThreadFirst.MaxFileSize=1000KB
log4j.appender.ThreadFirst.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.ThreadFirst.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ThreadFirst.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] (%F:%L) %-5p - %m%n

log4j.logger.com.ef.ThreadTwo=DEBUG, ThreadTwo

log4j.appender.ThreadTwo=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ThreadTwo.File=C:/AnalyzerLog/ThreadTwo/Analyzer.log
log4j.appender.ThreadTwo.MaxFileSize=1000KB
log4j.appender.ThreadTwo.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.ThreadTwo.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ThreadTwo.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] (%F:%L) %-5p - %m%n
```

Here are my logs file which my program is generating. this is thread one log file which is generating the logs for both thread 1 and thread 2

```
2014-01-24 15:24:13,688 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:76) DEBUG - Server is connect
2014-01-24 15:24:13,693 [Thread-0] (ServerAccess.java:76) DEBUG - Server is connect
2014-01-24 15:24:14,329 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter0
2014-01-24 15:24:14,414 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter1
2014-01-24 15:24:14,474 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter2
2014-01-24 15:24:14,534 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter3
2014-01-24 15:24:14,545 [Thread-0] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread OneCounter0
2014-01-24 15:24:14,589 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter4
2014-01-24 15:24:14,635 [Thread-0] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread OneCounter1
2014-01-24 15:24:14,639 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter5
2014-01-24 15:24:14,695 [Thread-0] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread OneCounter2
2014-01-24 15:24:14,724 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter6
2014-01-24 15:24:14,755 [Thread-0] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread OneCounter3
2014-01-24 15:24:14,809 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter7
2014-01-24 15:24:14,811 [Thread-0] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread OneCounter4
2014-01-24 15:24:14,861 [Thread-0] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread OneCounter5
2014-01-24 15:24:14,895 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter8
2014-01-24 15:24:14,947 [Thread-0] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread OneCounter6
2014-01-24 15:24:14,957 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter9
2014-01-24 15:24:15,019 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter10
2014-01-24 15:24:15,032 [Thread-0] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread OneCounter7
2014-01-24 15:24:15,079 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter11
2014-01-24 15:24:15,120 [Thread-0] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread OneCounter8
2014-01-24 15:24:15,139 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter12
2014-01-24 15:24:15,180 [Thread-0] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread OneCounter9
2014-01-24 15:24:15,194 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter13
2014-01-24 15:24:15,241 [Thread-0] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread OneCounter10
2014-01-24 15:24:15,281 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter14
2014-01-24 15:24:15,301 [Thread-0] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread OneCounter11
2014-01-24 15:24:15,362 [Thread-0] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread OneCounter12
2014-01-24 15:24:15,367 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter15
2014-01-24 15:24:15,417 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter16
2014-01-24 15:24:15,417 [Thread-0] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread OneCounter13
2014-01-24 15:24:15,503 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter17
2014-01-24 15:24:15,504 [Thread-0] (ServerAccess.java:97) DEBUG - Thread isThread OneCounter14
```

Here is thread 2 log file which is generating the logs only for his own thread

```
2014-01-27 10:56:56,582 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:77) DEBUG - Server is connect
2014-01-27 10:56:56,774 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:98) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter0
2014-01-27 10:56:56,897 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:98) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter1
2014-01-27 10:56:56,957 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:98) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter2
2014-01-27 10:56:57,017 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:98) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter3
2014-01-27 10:56:57,072 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:98) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter4
2014-01-27 10:56:57,122 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:98) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter5
2014-01-27 10:56:57,207 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:98) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter6
2014-01-27 10:56:57,292 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:98) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter7
2014-01-27 10:56:57,380 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:98) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter8
2014-01-27 10:56:57,440 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:98) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter9
2014-01-27 10:56:57,500 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:98) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter10
2014-01-27 10:56:57,560 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:98) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter11
2014-01-27 10:56:57,620 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:98) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter12
2014-01-27 10:56:57,686 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:98) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter13
2014-01-27 10:56:57,771 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:98) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter14
2014-01-27 10:56:57,856 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:98) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter15
2014-01-27 10:56:57,906 [Thread-1] (ServerAccess.java:98) DEBUG - Thread isThread TwoCounter16
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think log4j has support for this kind of separation. You should consider the logback framework (log4j is deprecated anyway). Logback comes with a SiftingAppender for log separation. For more information: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/loggingSeparation.html

It shouldn't be that difficult to use this SiftingAppender with your thread IDs as a discriminator.

Answer (score 0):

When instantiating your `ServerAccess` objects, give them the logger you want them to use like so:

`public class MainController {
    static void main (String[] args){
        Logger l1 = Logger.getLogger("log4j.logger.com.ef.ThreadOne");
        Logger l2 = Logger.getLogger("log4j.logger.com.ef.ThreadTwo");
        ServerAccess t1 = new ServerAccess(l1);
        ServerAccess t2 = new ServerAccess(l2);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }`

Then, within `ServerAccess`, use that logger like so:

`public class ServerAccess extends Thread {
    private final Logger logger;
    public ServerAccess(Logger logger){
        this.logger = logger;
    }
    public void Start() {
         logger.debug("Debug Statement");
    }
}`